# Worker Dyno go to sleep with the Web dyno

Tags: heroku

I'm using heroku to host my discord bot
My bot is mostly designed to be used with the discord chats,  but it have a web dashboard for when in need too. I put the bot on heroku, everything seems to be working well, I know about the 30 minutes sleep time for web dyno, and it was fine, since the web dashboard is only used every so often, not 24/24 like the bot. The issue here is, when the web dyno go offline, ***it also brought the worker dyno down too***, which is not what I wanted. Although the documents say that "Worker Dynos do not sleep, since they don't handle web requests", clearly that my worker dyno is sleeping with the web dyno. I don't want to use pinging services, since my 1000 free hours is not enough for both dynos to stay online. Is there a workaround for this? Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a workaround here that is free. In the end, the free tier is for apps not running all the time, and I totally understand Heroku that they will scale the workers to zero too.

Comment: Do you need the web dyno ? Only load up a worker dyno and then it should stay awake